# Dalvik VM Invocation issue

Tags: android, dalvik

I am trying to create a simple JAR file like [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/dalvik/docs/hello-world.html) and execute it in the shell. i am stuck on this line

```
dx --dex --output=foo.jar Foo.class
```

when i execute this line in CMD . I am always getting an error like this

```
trouble processing:
class name (com/delvix2/Foo) does not match path (C:/somepathhere/classes/com/delvix2/Foo.class)
...while parsing C:/somepathhere/classes/com/delvix2/Foo.class
...while processing C:/somepathhere/classes/com/delvix2/Foo.class
1 warning
no classfiles specified
```

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

`dx --dex --output="full path to dex file\file.dex" "c:\.....path to folder which contains the class file only"`

First path : full path to dex file including the name of the dex file you want

Second path : Path to a folder which contains "ONLY" your `.class` file.

(Just give the path up to the folder, don't give the class file name)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like dx expects that the relative path of the class that you give it will match it's package. Try this instead:

```
cd c:/somepathhere/classes
dx --dex --output=foo.jar com/delvix2/Foo.class
```

Comment: Thanks, Still same. I have updated the original question with an image. Please check

Comment: Please read my answer again :). You *must* use the relative path "com/delvix2/Foo.class" - exactly

Comment: FWIW, the path needs to _end_ with a matching path, as long as there's a path component "/./" immediately before the part that's supposed to match. So, for example, this should work too: `blort/spaz/./com/delvix2/Foo.class`

Comment: Ah! I didn't try that. Although that seems fairly non-obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--no-strict` option:

```
dx --dex --no-strict --output=foo.jar Foo.class
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be in your case

```
dx --dex --output=C:\classes.dex C:\temp\Foo.jar
```

and then you must use

```
aapt add C:\temp\Foo.jar C:\classes.dex
```

I hope it will be work

Answer (score 0):

I tried all this, and did not work. There's something that worked for me, and it was to put your classes in `\sdk-path\platforms-tools\`. For example,

```
C:\sdk-path\platforms-tools\dx --dex --output=class.dex  com\mypack\app\myclass.class
```

And myclass.class lives in,

```
C:\sdk-path\platforms-tools\com\mypack\app\myclass.class
```

This is crappy, but the only thing that worked.